# Django : pre-filled forms by database

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I created travels (pretty much like products) for my site and I want an admin to chnage some informations about those. So I created a form to change the informations. But I want the form to be pre-filled with the actual informations so the  admin just have to change what he wants to change.

I've been trying different ways to do it but it never worked.

Here is my form :

```
class ModifProduct(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta : 
        model = Product 
        fields = ['price', 'description','date','display']
        widget = {
            'price': forms.NumberInput(),
            'description': forms.Textarea(),
            'date': forms.DateInput(),
            'display': forms.CheckboxInput(),
        }
```

Here is my view :

```
def update_product(request, id):
    prod = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fm = ModifProduct(request.POST, instance=prod)
        if fm.is_valid():
            fm.save()
            return redirect("/accueil/gestion/")
    else: 
        fm = ModifProduct(instance=prod)
        
    context = {
        'form': fm,
    }
    return render(request, 'accueil/update_product.html', context)
```

The template is :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Modifier">
</form>
```

To access to this page, there is a button on the previous template :

```
<form action="{% url 'update_product' prod.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" value="Modifier">
</form>
```

I've tried the view :

```
def update_product(request, id):
    prod = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fm = ModifProduct(request.POST, instance=prod)
        if fm.is_valid():
            fm.save()
            return redirect("/accueil/gestion/")
    else: 
        fm = ModifProduct(instance=prod, initial={'price': prod.price, 'description': prod.description, 'date': prod.date, 'display': prod.display})
    context = {
        'form': fm,
    }
    return render(request, 'accueil/update_product.html', context)
```

I've tried the view :

```
def update_product(request, id):
    prod = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fm = ModifProduct(request.POST, instance=prod)
        if fm.is_valid():
            fm.save()
            return redirect("/accueil/gestion/")
    else: 
        fm = ModifProduct(instance=prod)
        fm.fields['price'].initial = prod.price
        fm.fields['description'].initial = prod.description
        fm.fields['date'].initial = prod.date
        fm.fields['display'].initial = prod.display
        
    context = {
        'form': fm,
    }
    return render(request, 'accueil/update_product.html', context)
```

Comment: Your view code seems to be fine, please see how to write a [mre]. You are probably rendering the input fields **manually** in the template.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll write a minimal reproducible example next time. What do you mean when you say "you are probably rendering the input fields manually "?

Comment: Ok, no you are letting Django render the form on its own. Are you sure this view itself is the one rendering your form? Or is it some other view which is rendering the form? Because you have passed the form the model instance so it will automatically use the existing object for initial values.

Comment: I'm sure this is the view, actually, I have the same problem with all of my form so I thought I was doing something wrong

Comment: I agree with Abdul. Code looks OK. Can you confirm, that this `Product.objects.get(pk=id)` product actually **has** data for `price`, `description` and so on stored in the database? Also you said that this should work for the admin. Is it working for the user already? Show us the part where you wire that view to the admin site.

Comment: I think I misspoke a little, when I say that an admin can change, the infos, I mean the admin is just a user in the group admin, that has access to this page that I did myself. And I can confirm there is data for the info related because to access to my change page, I come from another page with the infos visible in a table

Comment: Aha, I see the problem. "_To access to this page, there is a button on the previous template_" Why is this a POST request when it is sending no data? What is happening is your POST request has no data and the form created uses `request.POST` thinks user specifically removed everything and sends it back to them with errors. This request should have been a GET request. By the way why is that even a form? Why not just an anchor tag (styled as a button if you really want that)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed the problem. I'll be more carefull about when a form is needed and when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use template for your site, it's much easier than function base views:

```
class update_product(views.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'your html file for update'
    form_class = ModifProduct

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```